# syslog-ng difference between "not message(something)" and "not match(something)"?

Tags: syslog-ng

What is the difference between these two?:

```
filter f_avc { not message(something); };
```

and:

```
filter f_avc { not match(something); };
```

it's hard to google for these types of questions :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Documentation](http://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-v3.0-guide-admin-en.html/index.html-single.html#reference_filters) (my boldface):

> **Match** a regular expression to the headers and the message itself (i.e., the values returned by the *MSGHDR* and *MSG* macros).
>
> Match a regular expression to the text of the log **message**, excluding the headers (i.e., the value returned by the *MSG* macros).